# A proper holomorphic map is surjective

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, holomorphic-functions

I have been working on the following problem and was wondering if somebody can help me with one part of it.

> Let $U$ and $V$ be open and connected sets in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, and $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function with $f(U)\subseteq V$. Suppose that $f$ is a proper map from $U$ into $V$. Show that $f$ is surjective.

I have managed to show that necessarily $f(U)=V$ using the open mapping theorem and the fact $f$ is proper. Then my argument is that since $V$ is stated as just an open connected set such that $f(U)\subseteq V$ then we may take $V=\mathbb{C}$ because $\mathbb{C}$ quite obviously is open and connected.

Is this a sufficient argument? Or have I made a horrible assumption somewhere?

Comment: If you have shown $f(U)=V$ then you've succeeded and can stop. If you assume that $V=\Bbb C$ then you are in error, as it might not be.

Comment: *How* did you prove that $f(U)=V$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So the question is not asking to show that $f$ is surjective onto $\mathbb{C}$ but just that it is surjective onto $V$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Using $f$ proper show that if $f$ is constant then $U$ is the empty set. So supposing $U$ isn't empty $f$ is open by the open mapping theorem. Take an element $z_0\in V$. Then I can find a compact set  $K\subseteq V$ that intersects $f(U)$ then $f^{-1}(K)\subseteq U$ is compact and so there exists a point $w\in U$ such that $d(f(w),z_0)=d(f(U),z_0)$. Then $d=0$ so $z_0\in f(U)$ and so $f(U)=V$.

Comment: @ilikenumbers Consider $U=V$ and $f$ to be the identity function.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown ........... now I feel stupid. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your comment to @JoséCarlosSantos: I don't understand your proof.